# how to soap response parse in java in android

Tags: java, android, soap

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constant.NAME_SPACE, Constant.LOGIN_USER_BY_MOBILENUMBER);
request.addProperty("MobileNO", "8130513899");
request.addProperty("UserPassword", "12546");
envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constant.URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
androidHttpTransport.call(Constant.SOAP_ACTION_LOGIN_BY_USERMOBILE, envelope);
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject root = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(1);
SoapObject s_deals = (SoapObject) root.getProperty("LoginUserByMobileNoResult");
for (int i = 0; i < s_deals.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
    SoapObject s_deals_1 = (SoapObject) s_deals.getProperty(i);
    String x = s_deals_1.getProperty("UserEmail").toString();
    String y = s_deals_1.getProperty("UserMobile").toString();
    String z = s_deals_1.getProperty("UserMpin").toString();
}
```

This is my code, I am able to get data result but I have to parse and fetch data from response. Please tell me where am doing mistake in code.

Below is my response:

> LoginUserByMobileNoResponse{LoginUserByMobileNoResult={"UserId":"2","UserParentId":"1","UserName":"Anilkumar","UserPassword":"12546","UserMobile":"8133513899","UserEmail":"anilaasdt87@gmail.com","UserMpin":"7890","UserBalance":"20.0000","UserResponseMessage":"Is Valid"}; }

I want to get all data like UserMobile, UserEmail.. please tell me how to get it.